# I accidentally split my imported txt file so every string was on a line by itself

Tags: arrays, string

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQkt5.png)

I was trying to put a list of strings ("eggs, alfalfa sprouts, bean sprouts, cabbage, tomatoes, etc) into an array. I did this however, it put each string onto a line by itself. I essentially need to correct this so it outputs "bean sprouts" and "alfalfa sprouts" on the same line not "alfalfa" then "sprouts" on the line below it. Attached is my code as well as the output that it is giving me.

Comment: Use `nextLine()` instead of `next()`.  `next()` only reads up to a space which is why it's not outputting properly

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was a simple error but I am a beginning programmer. Thanks for the quick help!